# Почему vite вставляет index.css последним?

Tags: css, reactjs, vite

Простой вопрос - есть проект react, созданный на vite
зависимости:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.14",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^4.5.0"
  }
```

файл конфигурации vite:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

файлы стилей импортируются так, что index.css импортируется последним.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы index.css шел первым?
Спасибо за помощь